# Limit rows checked with a not in query - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have 2 tables. `TableA` that has 350K rows and `TableB` has only the active data that `TableA` is supposed to have. So I need to clear out the old data in `TableA`.

This query would be great if `Table A` wasn't so large.

```
DELETE FROM TableA where MLS NOT IN (SELECT LIST_3 FROM TableB);
```

So what I need to do is limit the number of rows checked in `TableA`. Instead of it checking 350K records from `TableA` I want it to check 100 for example.

I can't figure out how... This doesn't work because it only limits the number of rows deleted and not checked. It may check 500 rows and delete 100. I want it to check 100 and delete however many aren't in `TableB`.

```
DELETE FROM TableA where MLS NOT IN (SELECT LIST_3 FROM TableB) LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: Which database you are using?What about rownum?

Answer (score 1):

If `TableA` has a primary key, you could do this as:

```
DELETE a
    FROM TableA a JOIN
         (SELECT a2.id
          FROM TableA a2
          LIMIT 100  -- should have an order by with limit
         ) a2
         ON a.id = a2.id
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableB b WHERE b.List_3 = a.MLS);
```

Notes:

- The join using the primary key should be quite fast, even with the subquery.
- I changed the `NOT IN` to `NOT EXISTS`.  The latter has more intuitive behavior when there are `NULL` values.
- You should always use `ORDER BY` with `LIMIT`, but your original question didn't specify a way of choosing *which* 100 rows to look for.

Comment: It's not a primary key, the columns I'm comparing are VARCHAR.

Comment: @skoltyno . . . I'm saying you should use a primary key such as `id`, not that one of the columns is a primary key.  And the type of the columns is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

A left join on indexed columns should perform a delete fairly fast:

```
delete a
from TableA a 
left join TableB b on a.MLS = b.LIST_3
where b.LIST_3 is null;
```

SqlFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2e1e0/1